# Can i get data sum filtered ajax datatable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, sum, codeigniter-3

I have data and I am fetching ajax data. Now I have a problem when I filter the data I can't take the filtered amount, can I get the filtered data so I can get the data directly without having to calculate manually. and here is the code i have :

Script :

```
// render order list data table
// default render page
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {doc_no:"", name:"", startDate: "", endDate: ""};
    generateOrderTable(data);
});

// render date datewise
jQuery(document).on('click','#filter-order-filter', function(){
    var startDate = jQuery('input#order-end-date').val();//jQuery('input#order-start-date').val();
    var endDate = jQuery('input#order-end-date').val();
    var data = {startDate:startDate, endDate:endDate};
    generateOrderTable(data);
});
// generate Order Table
function generateOrderTable(element){
    jQuery.ajax({
        //url: baseurl + 'dokumen/getOrderList',
        url: "<?php echo site_url('saldo/getSalbankList')?>",
        data: {'start_date' : element.startDate , 'end_date' : element.endDate},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        
        beforeSend: function () {
            jQuery('#render-list-of-order').html('<div class="text-center mrgA padA"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-4x fa-fw"></i></div>');
        },
        success: function (html) { 
            var dataTable='<table id="order-datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>';
            jQuery('#render-list-of-order').html(dataTable); 
            
            var table = $('#order-datatable').DataTable({

                data: html.data,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "pageLength": 50,
                "bFilter": false, 
                "bInfo": true,
                "bAutoWidth": true,
               
                columns: [
                    { title: "ID", "width": "10%"},
                    { title: "Bank", "width": "20%"},
                    { title: "Saldo", "width": "10%"},
                    { title: "Date", "width": "10%"},
                    
                ],
             
 
                //END
            });
            
              
        }
    });
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="row clearfix">
                        <!-- CLEARFIX -->
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!--<div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="date" name="order_start_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d")?>" class="form-control getDatePicker" id="order-start-date" placeholder="Start date">
                                    </div>
                                </div>-->
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="date" name="order_end_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d")?>" class="form-control getDatePicker" id="order-end-date" placeholder="End date">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button name="filter_order_filter" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block filter_order_filter" id="filter-order-filter" value="filter"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                    <div class="card-body p-1" style="background: #4ef3ae">
                                    <h5>Rp <span id="total"></span></h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata("msg");?>
                            <div id="render-list-of-order">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

How to do this. Can anyone help me how to do?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "_take the filtered amount_". Can you try to describe your problem in a different way?